Where is the date format of the SC website set?
I wrote an extension that uses SC.ENVIRONMENT.siteSettings.dateformat to get the website date format, but I found that the formats of the sandbox and the production are different. Where can I change this date format?

The date format set in the production is DD/MM/YYYY, but the date format obtained through SC.ENVIRONMENT.siteSettings.dateformat is MM/DD/YYYY
